# Cannot interpret compiler warning

Tags: c

My compiler (gcc) throws warnings (not errors!) on the line which declares `fp`:

```
int fd = open("filename.dat", O_RDONLY);
FILE* fp = fdopen(fd, "r"); // get a file pointer fp from the file descriptor fd
```

These are the warnings:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:606: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fdopen’
main.c:606: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

I do not understand these warnings since the return value of `fopen` is a `FILE*`. What is the mistake I am making here?

**EDIT**: I am including `stdio.h` (and I am also on Linux).

Comment: @robert: stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h, errno.h, unistd.h, sys/types.h, sys/stat.h, fcntl.h

Comment: Does `man fdopen` list any headers that you don't have?

Comment: @robert: no, it lists on `stdio.h`.

Comment: Which compiler flags are you using?

Comment: I'm using `gcc 4.4.3` with `-g -O0 -std=c99 -Wall`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Short answer*: use `-std=gnu99` when compiling, the usual standard is non-POSIX and does not have `fdopen`.

---

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fdopen’
```

Means you have forgot to include the header file which the declaration of `fdopen()` resides in. Then an implicit declaration by the compiler occurs - and that means the return value of the unknown function will be assumed to be `int` - thus the second warning. You have to write

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Edit: if you properly include stdio.h, then `fdopen()` might not be available on the system you're targeting. Are you on Windows? This function is POSIX-only.

Edit 2: Sorry, I really should have perceived this. C99 means the ANSI C99 standard - and standard C doesn't force the concept of file descriptors in order to support non-POSIX systems, so it provides `fopen()` only. **`fdopen()` is related to file descriptors, so it's POSIX-only, so it's not part of standard C99. If you use the `-std=gnu99` switch for GCC, it gets rid of the standard's restrictions** and lets in the POSIX and GNU-only extensions, essentially fixing your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I **am** including `stdio.h` (see edit).

Comment: @pap42 you might be using windows. If that's the case, I suggest you to cease and desist.

Comment: @pap42 are you using a compiler option that restricts you to C89 and/or ANSI-C only? I'm looking at `gcc -std=c89 -ansi`...

Comment: I'm compiling with `gcc` using the flags: `-g -O0 -std=c99 -Wall`.

Comment: @pap42 if you use `-std=gnu99` instead, does it help?

Comment: Bingo, you got it! Could you please edit your answer and explain this?

Answer (score 2):

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <stdio.h>
```

This conforms perfectly with strict c99

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not including `#include <stdio.h>` in C the compiler therefore "guesses" the declaration of the function you're trying to call. (Taking the parameters you've based and using int as return value). Usually you don't want such guesses  therefore the compiler warns you.

Solution: Add proper `#include`s.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is incorrect. I am including `stdio.h` (see edit).

Comment: What system are you on? - POSIX says `fdopen()` has to be in `stdio.h`  (or in a header included by stdio.h) - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fdopen.html

Comment: I'm on Linux (and I'm equally baffled by this warning since I am including `stdio.h`).

Comment: `fdopen` is *conditionally* declared in `<stdio.h>`; see the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `fdopen` function is not part of the C standard and is not available as part of the standard headers if you compile in standard C mode. So you either need to use `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99` to compile your source or declare the function yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good explanation for the compiler's diagnostic in @H2CO3's answer, so let's only look on the *why* of things: if you're using glibc (and you probably are), certain POSIX functions may require specific *feature test macros* to show up.

In particular, you may need to put the following line:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
// or #define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

before

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Certain compilers (such as gcc) also have command line options to the same effect (all the `gnu*` standards options in gcc).

Comment: This is right in principle, but `_POSIX_SOURCE` is from the outdated early-90s version of the POSIX standard. The modern name is `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` and it can't just be defined to a blank definition; it has to be defined to the version you want. `200809L` is the correct value for the current standard.